# How to wait until an element is invisible

Tags: c#, selenium, pageobjects

I Need to wait for an element to be NOT visible 
and found a couple of solutions for this, but none of them seems to work for me.

I think the problem is because I'm using PageObject Models. but I'm not complete sure.

```
 public static void WaitForElementToBeInvisible(this Browser browser, IWebElement element, int seconds = 30)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(browser.Driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, seconds));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(element));
        }
```

But it returns error `cannot convert from IWebElement to Selenium.By`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add function calling code as well?

Comment: From this exception, you are passing Iwebelement instead of By locator.

Comment: Hello Dymond, I have done ton of research on this and coding with selenium c# since 6+ months and from my knowledge this is not possible. Some things about the Page Object design pattern don't make sense and you chould try to do this with a `By` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answer, but solved it like this.

```
public static void WaitUntilInvisible(this Browser browser, By element, int seconds = 30)
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(browser.Driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, seconds));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(element));
        }
```

Then used as By locator

```
By LoadingIcon = By.XPath(".//*[contains(@class, 'loading')]");
```

works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, this is not possible. The developers of Selenium have decided that there are no useful use cases for this.

If `By` locator is possible, you can use:

```
  public static void WaitUntilInvisible(this By locator)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Driver.FindElement(locator).Displayed)
                {
                    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(locator));
                }
        }
```

See also: [Trying to convert IWebElement into a By element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36888327/trying-to-convert-iwebelement-into-a-by-element/41548083#41548083)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect. It calls `InvisibilityOfElementLocated` which doesn't receive IWebElement as a parameter. See my example below.

```
public static bool WaitForElementToBeInvisible(this IWebElement element, int timeoutSecond = 10)
{
    IWait<IWebElement> wait = new DefaultWait<IWebElement>(element);
    wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutSecond);
    wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);
    try
    {
        wait.Until(!element.Displayed);
    }
    catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

IWebElement div = driver.FindElement(By.Id("id"));
var result = div.WaitForElementToBeInvisible(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do { Playback.Wait(100); } while (_driver.FindElements(By.Id("elementId")).Count() > 0);
```