# retrieve xpath or other element identifier from a python program

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to do something i can't find any help on. I want to be able to locate the xpath or other 'address' information in of a particular element for later use by selenium. I have text for the element and can find it using the selenium `By.LINK.TEXT` methodology. However, i am writing an application where speed is critical so i want to pre-find the element, store the xpath (for later use) and then use the `By.XPATH` methodology. In general finding an element using the `BY.text` construction takes .5 seconds whereas the xpath lookup takes on 10 - 20% of that time. I tried the code below but i get an error on getpath (`WebElement object has no attribute getpath`)

Thanks for any help

```
temp = br.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, (str(day_to_book)))

print(temp.getpath())
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The Selenium `WebElement` object received by `driver.find_element(ByLocator)` is **already** a reference to the actual physical web element on the page. In other words, the `WebElement` object is an address of the actual web element you asking about.
2. There is [no way to get a By locator of an already found WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31676964/get-the-by-locator-of-an-already-found-webelement)

So, in your particular example `temp = br.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, (str(day_to_book)))` the `temp` is an address of the element you can keep for future use (until the page is changed / refreshed)

Comment: 1. So if the page changes and eventually comes back to this page the address retrieved above no longer works? and (2) How would i use that address in selenium to open the page? What find_element_by search would i use?  Thanks SO VERY MUCH!

Comment: Right. This causes Stale element reference error. See here for more explanations: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/StaleElementReference

Comment: the second question is not clear

Comment: To Prophet (nice handle!): Thanks so much for the tender treatment and referrals. I'll figure something out from here.